# Delphi android notification accent color problem

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

The notification icon an android 8 is always white? I have a Delphi android project with a custom notification icon. When I receive a notification it always has a White accent. Of course I can change the accent color of the notification image from the project option. However I want the notification image to appear as it is, without any color accent. I tried to disable accent color checkbox from the protect option but that didn't work.

Disabled color accent, still same problem. white accent color

Notification code : Add Notification center componeent.

```
var
    MyNotification: TNotification;
  begin
    MyNotification := NotificationCenter.CreateNotification;
    try
      MyNotification.Name := 'MyNotification';
      MyNotification.AlertBody := 'Delphi for your mobile device is here!';
      // MyNotification.AlertAction.
      // Fired in 10 seconds
      MyNotification.FireDate := Now + EncodeTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
      // Send notification to the notification center
      NotificationCenter.ScheduleNotification(MyNotification);
    finally
      MyNotification.DisposeOf;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Try to add some code so people can help you. There may be some bugs and adding code to your question can be helpful for those answering.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code is irrelevant, but there you go, check update @Juncu

Comment: As far as I know notification icons on [Android 5.0 and later](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop/android-5.0-changes#NotificationsMaterialDesignStyle) are always drawn with an accent color.